# "nfsd peername failed" but NFSv4 service functions

Tags: centos6, nfs, keepalived, nfs4

My current setup: 2 NFS servers sharing the same directory with identical content, 1 `keepalived` server as SLB (or rather for failover in this scenario), and 1 NFSv4 client mounting through VIP. All systems run CentOS 6 (2.6.32-573.26.1.el6.x86_64). And because this is a testing environment, all machines are on the same subnet (192.168.66.xx). For reference, the IPs are as below.

```
99 VIP
100 nfs01
101 nfs02
102 client
103 keepalived01
```

The NFS servers are configured as such:

```
/root/share 192.168.66.0/24(ro,fsid=0,sync,no_root_squash
```

As for `keepalived`, I am running it in DR mode (NAT mode fails to work at all).

```
vrrp_instance nfs {
        interface eth0
                state MASTER
                virtual_router_id 51
                priority 103    # 103 on master, 101 on backup
                authentication {
                        auth_type PASS
                        auth_pass hiServer
                }
        virtual_ipaddress {
                192.168.66.99/24 dev eth0
        }
}

virtual_server 192.168.66.99 2049 {
    delay_loop 6
    lb_algo wlc
    lb_kind DR
    protocol TCP

    real_server 192.168.66.100 2049 {
            weight 100
            TCP_CHECK {
                    connect_timeout 6
                    connect_port 2049
            }
    }

    real_server 192.168.66.101 2049 {
            weight 102
            TCP_CHECK {
                    connect_port 2049
                    connect_timeout 6
            }
    }
}
```

Lastly the client mounts via this command:

```
mount -t nfs4 192.168.66.99:/ /nfsdata
```

The NFSv4 mount seems to function, though I haven't stress-tested it. One thing I notice is a period of time during failover, i.e. I shut down one of the NFS servers forcing `keepalived` to move service to another NFS server, that the client will seem to hang for some time before responding. I believe this is due to the 90-second grace period.

The problem that nags me is that on the NFS servers, this line of log keeps showing every or so seconds, flooding the logs.

```
kernel: nfsd: peername failed (err 107)!
```

I've tried using `tcpdump` to see what is causing the traffic and spotted repeating exchanges beteween the NFS server and the `keepalived` server. At first I thought `iptables` could be the culprit, but flushing them on both machines does not stop the error.

If there is a way to suppress the error I may call it a day (is there?), but my curiosity questions: does the NFS server have a reason to try to communicate with the `keepalived` server in this scenario? Or perhaps there is something fundamentally wrong when setting up NFS HA this way, even though it seems to work?

Comment: looks like client disconnects right after connecting

Answer (score 1):

Upon further inspection, the error `kernel: nfsd: peername failed (err 107)!` appears approximately every 6 seconds. The number seems to correspond to the `connection_timeout` option in the conf file, and indeed by stopping `keepalived` service, the error stops appearing altogether.

It seems by using `TCP_CHECK` on port 2049, the NFS servers will log the "bad" connection attempts since `keepalived` is not sending NFS messages according to protocol.

In the end I use `MISC_CHECK` instead to check for NFS servers' health (with a custom shell script calling `rpcinfo`).